# How to modify network connection from Java integration test?

Tags: java, rest, networking, junit, jersey

I've written a Java class (`MyRestClient`) that needs to hit a third-party RESTful API and do some processing with the HTTP response returned from their server. I'm now trying to write a series of successful integration tests (using `JUnit` as the underlying testng lib) between `MyRestClient` and the 3rd party API to make sure this class behaves correctly under a variety of circumstances:

- Everything is perfect (RESTful API call was correct and the server returns a meaningful response)
- Bad API call and server returns an application-layer error code
- A variety of non-200 HTTP codes get returned, including 403, 404 and 500
- No network connection
- ...etc.

The 4th item on that list ("*No network connection*") is what I'm currently stuck on. I'm using [`Jersey`](http://jersey.java.net/) under the hood to perform my actual REST calls, however Jersey is itself just based on `java.net.*`. If at all possible, I'd like to "break" Jersey's/Java's ability to fire a network connection while my `shouldThrowExceptionOnBadNetworkConnection()` test method is executing, and then turn it back "on" so that the next test method can behave normally.

I've been looking at the [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) which seems to do just this, however there doesn't seem to be a Java library for managing it at runtime.

So I ask: **How do I turn Java networking "off" for a specific integration test?** Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider using a mocking library such as mockito?

Comment: Thanks @fge but please see my comment underneath Bohemian's answer - basically Mockito (and its likes) are great for mocking/stubbing dependencies....but I don't want to mock/stub these API calls! I want to actually use them, and simulate a network outage.

Comment: Which a mock library can do for you, so where is the problem?

Comment: Ultimately a mock library can only *mock* Java objects. It can say "hey, normally this object's method does *ABC*, but instead I want it to do *DEF*." **I don't want this**. I want all the Java objects (my objects, Jersey objects and any `java.net.*` objects) to behave like they normally do. But when Jersey/Java goes (at the network layer) to make a connection to these 3rd party servers, I don't want them to be able to because the (non-Java) operating system see a network outage.

Comment: Like I mentioned, the Charles proxy can do this, but Java mocking libs like Mockito or EasyMock cannot. **That's where the problem is.**

Comment: I'm afraid you're wrong, mock libraries can do what you describe. Consider that a mock object returned by `Mockito.mock()` has both `when().thenReturn()` and `when().thenThrow()`.

Comment: I am also afraid that you do not make the distinction between unit testing and integration testing. There is no way to "turn the network off" in integration testings, they can fail for that reason, or not, depending on when they are run. Using mock libraries, on the other hand, allows you to test for such events. Testing network failure is _not_ the role of integration testing.

Comment: Listen, I'm not going to argue here. Both the `thenReturn()` and `thenThrow()` methods are used for [stubbing](); i.e., returning a different value (or in the case of the exception, throwing it) then the method normally would return. Both of these methods involve the use of [test doubles](). The only thing you've said that I *might* agree with is that "testing network failure is not the role of integration testing." I think the case can be argued either way.

Comment: But at the end of the day, Mockito and every method you listed can only simulate a network outage at the Java layer. I want to do this at the system layer, outside of Java (but control this from a Java test method). If you don't know the answer to that, that's fine; I'm sure there's someone on SO that does.

Comment: " I want to do this at the system layer, outside of Java" <-- you can't, which is why mocking frameworks exist at all ;)

Comment: Of course you can, for instance I could write a shell script that used `iptables` to block every port on my machine, and then call that shell script from my Java test method. I'm looking for something more elegant than that, and the Charles proxy (see link in original post) seems to be the right tool for the job. I'm just looking for the best way to control that (or something like it) from Java.

Comment: And then again, mock frameworks are what you want. For one, they don't require that you run as root. I really don't see where the problem is, to be honest.

Comment: I assume at this point that you're just trolling me. If so, well done good sir (that's usually my role). Either way, I'm interested to hear what other SO patrons have to say.

Comment: OK, look: even if you did have the ability to turn networking on and off, _nothing ever guarantees that results will be predictable at all_, because your tests would require that... Yes... Networking behave the way you want. You have NO control over that _at all_. The one and only way you can test for the behavior of your classes is to fake what should happen. And by now you know what is needed. I know, I also test for such conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Make MyRestClient testable by having it declare a protected method that returns the URL and have it use that instead if a private field.

In your JUnit test, you an anonymous class to override that method do it returns junk:

```
MyRestClient willFail = new MyRestClient() {
    protected String getUrl() {
        return "http://not.a.real.address";
    }
}
```

There are also mocking libraries that can do similar things

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian - but what you are talking about is valid for *unit* testing, where the objective is to isolate classes from their dependencies and to test them as standalones. I am talking about *integration* testing, and want to actively test `MyRestClient` against the actual 3rd party API. In this scenario, I want to simulate a network outage, and make sure `MyRestClient` handles that situation appropriately.